# Mpi program cannot run in Vscode on Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mpi

I was trying to run some mpi programs, and I downloaded the .exe and .msi files from the official website.

After installing, I tried running the sample code without success.

At first, the error message said that mpi.h could not be found. I tried adding the path where mpi.h is located in the including path, and the error disappeared.

But there are still some errors that I cannot find the ways to solve.

Here are my configurations:

tasks.json:

```
 "tasks": [
            {
                "type": "cppbuild",
                "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
                "command": "D:\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
                "args": [
                    "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                    "-g",
                    "${file}",
                    "-I",
                    "${MSMPI_INC}",
                    "-L",
                    "${MSMPI_LIB64}",
                    "-lmsmpi",
                    "-o",
                    "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
                ],
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
            }
        ],
        "version": "2.0.0"
    }
```

c_cpp_properties:

```
{
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Win32",
                "includePath": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\MPI\\Include"
                ],
                "defines": [
                    "_DEBUG",
                    "UNICODE",
                    "_UNICODE"
                ],
                "compilerPath": "D:\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
                "cStandard": "c17",
                "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
                "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
            }
        ],
        "version": 4
    }
```

Demo code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  cout << "hello" << endl;
  int myid, numprocs;
  int namelen;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);
  cout << "Hello World! Process" << myid << "of" << numprocs << " on " << processor_name << endl;
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
[Running] cd "d:\BuildYourOwnX\AAPP\" && g++ demo.cpp -o demo -fopenmp -l msmpi -L "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64" -I "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include" && mpiexec -n 4 demo
'mpiexec' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
���������ļ���

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.979 seconds
```